RS232-RS485-CAN-Board erros
I've got this marvelous pi hat
RS232-RS485-CAN-Board
With this config:
enable_uart=1
kernel=u-boot.bin

[all]
device_tree=bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
dtparam=spi=on
dtoverlay=i2c0
dtoverlay=spi1-3cs
dtoverlay=sc16is752-spi1,int_pin=25
dtoverlay=mcp2515,spi0-0,oscillator=16000000,interrupt=23
dtoverlay=mcp251xfd,spi0-1,interrupt=24

And both can interfaces won't show at the same time, not sure why
When I comment out one of them the other show's up in the ifconfig
Additionally, the mcp2515 works but the mcp251xfd fails with this:
[ 52.157476] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): can0: link becomes ready
[ 52.167715] NOHZ tick-stop error: Non-RCU local softirq work is pending, handler #08!!!
[ 53.040857] mcp251xfd spi0.1 can0: bus-off, scheduling restart in 100 ms
[ 53.047739] NOHZ tick-stop error: Non-RCU local softirq work is pending, handler #08!!!
[ 53.167475] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): can0: link becomes ready
[ 54.038527] mcp251xfd spi0.1 can0: bus-off, scheduling restart in 100 ms
[ 54.045380] NOHZ tick-stop error: Non-RCU local softirq work is pending, handler #08!!!
[ 54.164644] NOHZ tick-stop error: Non-RCU local softirq work is pending, handler #08!!!
[ 54.177464] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): can0: link becomes ready
[ 55.038128] mcp251xfd spi0.1 can0: bus-off, scheduling restart in 100 ms
[ 55.187477] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): can0: link becomes ready
[ 56.040062] mcp251xfd spi0.1 can0: bus-off, scheduling restart in 100 ms
[ 56.197468] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): can0: link becomes ready

It's on Venus OS for RPI
I'm lost and have no idea how to solves those 2 issues
Thanks in advance!
